# error occured while adding a content type in drupal 7.22

Tags: drupal

i need a content type of calender and added all the modules required
but while adding content type the following error occures 
the following message is displayed in the browser while i tried to add add content type...
[enter image description here][1]cured..

Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
Original

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT nt.* FROM {node_type} nt WHERE (disabled = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ORDER BY nt.type ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 0 ) in _node_types_build() (line 744 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\node\node.module).
Additional

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT ff.* FROM {filter_format} ff WHERE (status = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ORDER BY weight ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 ) in filter_formats() (line 427 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\filter\filter.module).
Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in _drupal_session_write() (line 209 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\session.inc).

Comment: Restart your mysql server :)

Comment: i have restarted the mysql server but its not solved

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for "Mysql server has gone away" is the max_packet_size setting. Add this on your .ini:

max_allowed_packet      = 64M